# Example: Irreducible component - affine varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

[image]

Again, I know how to prove the statement. But, I cannot find any example. Please help me for finding an example. Thank you:)

Comment: Nice handwriting there. Whose is it?

Comment: My handwriting thank you:) @GeorgesElencwajg

Comment: Congratulations, dear  B11b: I'm green with envy:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=2$, take for $X$ the circle $x^2+y^2=1$, for $H$ the "hypersurface" $y=0$ ( a good old line!) and then  $X\cap H$ consists of the two irreducible  components (=points)  $\{(-1,0)\}$ and $\{(1,0)\}$.